# jQuery UI dialog open

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to open a dialog window from code. The internet says to use $("#dialog").dialog("open"); but for some reason this isn't working.

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      alert("Hello World!");
      $("dialog").dialog('open');
    }
  });
  $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
});
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 200,
    width: 150
  });
});
```

I want it to open when a user stops moving one of the list items. The alert occurs but not the dialog. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed `#`

```
 $("#dialog").dialog('open');
```

Comment: Oh gosh! I hate it when things like this happen. Thanks ;)